# typeerror: no implicit conversion of hash into string when calling model.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using

```
ruby version 2.2.6
rails version 4.1.16
postgresql 11.10
gem json-1.8.6
```

Currently I am getting the error "typeerror: no implicit conversion of hash into string" when I am trying to save a model. This only happen for param that is using json datatype.

The database schema for the table:

```
create_table "jasons", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.json "description"
end
```

I already entered accessors for using json in the Jason.rb model like this.

```
class Jason < ApplicationRecord
  :description, accessors: [:key1, :key2, :watapak]
end
```

and also whitelisted the params in the controller.

```
    def jason_params
      params.require(:jason).permit(:name, :description, :key1, :key2, :watapak)
    end
```

and I can call new on the model successfully with

```
jason = Jason.new(name: "Jason John", key1: "abcd", key2: "efgh")
  => #<Jason id: nil, name: "Jason John", description: {"key1"=>"abcd", "ke...
```

then when I'm trying to call jason.save, it return's the error "typeerror: no implicit conversion of hash into string".

I tested the code on another environment, using the latest ruby 3.0 and rails 6.1 and everything works great without any error.

One thing that I notice is that the SQL command on both environment is different.

```
Rails 6.1

Jason Create (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "jasons" ("name", "description") VALUES (?, ?)  [["name", "Jason John"], ["description", "\"--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess\\nkey1: abcd\\nkey2: efgh\\n\""]]


Rails 4.1.6

SQL (6.6ms) INSERT INTO "device_models" ("created_at", “name", "description", “updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id" [["“created at", "2021-08-09 07:13:04.157826"], ["name", “Jason John"], ["description", "{\"key1\":\"abcd\",\"key2\":\"efgh\"}"], ["updated at", "2021-08-09 07:13:04.157826"]]
```

The full error is as in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eCgC.png). Also it differs a bit with the question but the root of the problem is the same.
Do tell me if more information is needed. Also sorry if my question is gibberish as this is my first time posting question, I don't really know how to structure it to make it simpler to understand.

Please help T.T

Comment: I think you are seeing a name collision. I strongly urge you to choose a class name that is not `Json`. It's almost certainly colliding with Ruby's `Json` class.

Comment: `:description, accessors: [:key1, :key2, :watapak]` is a syntax error. You're most likely missing the method that you intended to call.

Comment: @LesNightingill I think no name collision as it is working in my testing environment, Rails 6.1

Comment: @max yeah thats correct a bit of mistype here. In my machine I already write it like that "store :description, accessors: [:key1, :key2, :watapak]". Gonna try using the store_accessor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you may have intend to write `store :description, accessors: [:key1, :key2, :watapak]` which is a hack to store serialized data in a VARCHAR/TEXT columns and does not work with native JSON types. Both [`serialize`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) and [`store`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) are practically obsolete.

> NOTE: If you are using structured database data types (e.g. PostgreSQL
> hstore/json, or MySQL 5.7+ json) there is no need for the
> serialization provided by .store. Simply use .store_accessor instead
> to generate the accessor methods. Be aware that these columns use a
> string keyed hash and do not allow access using a symbol.

```
class Jason < ApplicationRecord
  store_accessor :description, :key1, :key2, :watapak
end
```

Comment: thanks! this works great! although i still don't quite understand what's the problem as both rails 6.1 and rails 4.2 environment are using postgresql. Anyways kudos max!

Comment: The problem is that the database driver (the pg gem) handles serializing and de-serializing JSON columns for you - so it passes a hash back. `serialize` is a hack from back before native JSON columns where available and expects to get a string from the database driver.